# SQL Window function to divide a column into 4 groups

Tags: sql, sum, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to divide the rows in such a way that the sum of revenue of each group is approx equal (in this case 50)

See groups here:

[image: See groups here]

Comment: What if you have 6 rows, one with 150 and the five others with 10? What you ask for is complex, you need to describe precisely how you imagine this would work.

Comment: @GMB Thanks for the revert, in the case above 5 rows with 10 will fall into group 1 while row with 150 will fall into group 4. Basically I want to divide revenue into 25% equal revenue groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using window functions:

```
select
    usr,
    revenue, 
    r_revenue running_revenue,
    sum(case 
        when lag_r_revenue is null or r_revenue / divisor <> lag_r_revenue / divisor 
        then 1 else 0 
    end) over(order by revenue, usr) grp
from (
    select t.*, lag(r_revenue) over(order by revenue, usr) lag_r_revenue
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            sum(revenue) over(order by revenue, usr) r_revenue, 
            sum(revenue) over() / 4 divisor
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
order by running_revenue
```

The most inner subquery computes the running sum of `revenue` (aliased `r_revenue`); it also computes the target revenue per group by dividing the total revenue by 4.

The next level adds the previous running revenue to each row (`lag_r_revenue`).

Finally, the outer query does a window sums that increases everytime the (integer) ratio between the running sum and the target amount per group changes.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9eb14af233a260a58c12138303c5bf70)**:

```
usr | revenue | running_revenue | grp
--: | ------: | --------------: | --:
  1 |       5 |               5 |   1
  2 |       5 |              10 |   1
  3 |      10 |              20 |   1
  4 |      15 |              35 |   1
  5 |      15 |              50 |   2
  6 |      20 |              70 |   2
  7 |      20 |              90 |   2
  8 |      25 |             115 |   3
  9 |      30 |             145 |   3
 10 |      55 |             200 |   4
```

Comment: You would need to have recursion to solve these kinds of problems i feel, try setting 5 users each with value of 5. This wouldnt work if we are to make use of window functions which pre-computes the values based on the existing records in the table

Answer (score 0):

To solve these kind of problems you would need a recursive cte. Here i have a table with equal values of 5 for 5 records. so per grp you would expect 1 since would be 25/4 > 5

```
create table data_tbl
as 
select * from (values
        (1, 5), 
        (2, 5),
        (3, 5),
        (4, 5),
        (5, 5)
          ) as t(user1, revenue)

 with recursive data
      as (select user1
                 ,revenue
                 ,(sum(revenue) over())/4 as qtr_revenue
                 ,cast(1 as int) as grp
            from data_tbl
           where user1=1 /* start with the first user*/
         union all
          select b.user1
                 ,case when b.revenue+a.revenue<=a.qtr_revenue then
                                  b.revenue+a.revenue
                             else b.revenue
                   end as revenue
                 ,a.qtr_revenue
                 ,case when b.revenue+a.revenue<=a.qtr_revenue then
                                  a.grp
                             else a.grp+1
                   end as grp
            from data a
            join data_tbl b
              on b.user1=a.user1+1
          )
    select *
      from data
    order by user1
```

See db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d8d0d85e4d825af63c09f311302e3510